# How can I implement both hourly and weekly seasonality in Fable - R Package using season() function?

Tags: forecasting, fable-r, tsibble

I have to create hourly forecasts for 2000 different time series. And I have strong hourly and weekly seasonality in my series. To deal with hourly seasonality I used `season("day")` option. However, I suppose `season("week")` would create 168 weekly dummies and that would be problem on computional problem.

Do you know a quick way to create dayofweek dummies using tsibble or fabletools packages.

```
ts_forecast1 <- train%>% filter(store_number==288) %>% collect()%>% 
mutate(store_number = factor(store_number)) %>% group_by(store_number) %>%  
filter(sales!=0) %>% tsibble::fill_gaps(sales=100) %>%
fabletools::model(Arima = ARIMA(log(sales) ~  season("day") +fourier("week", K = 8)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code already contains the answer.

`season("day")` will create 23 dummy variables since there are 24 hours in a day. `season("week")` will create 167 dummy variables for the 168 hours in a week. To use fewer coefficients, replace `season()` with `fourier()` and use `K` to control the number of coefficients (equal to twice `K`).

Comment: I think most important problem here is to finding right K for the algorithm. There were some examples on solving seasonality issues with fourier() on your book, https://otexts.com/fpp2/complexseasonality.html/  but I am still unsure for the right level. Although I have used the for loop given in the book to find most accurate K I couldn't run the loop because of number of coefficient restrictions.  I am using tsibble object with hourly data but I am still receiving   K must be not be greater than period/2 error